# Rank Nullity and Dimension relation

Tags: linear-algebra, relations

How would one prove the relations:

$rank S◦T = rankT-dim(kerS ∩ ImT)$

and

$nullity S◦T = nullityT+dim(kerS ∩ ImT)$

I understand that the use of rank nullity theorem is required but am confused by the composition.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful to recognize here that the composition $S \circ T$ is *basically* (although not really) the restriction of $S$ to $\text{Im}(T)$. Under this restriction, apply the rank-nullity theorem, and the result should come out.

Comment: thanks for your response, however I am not aware of this terminology, can you explain it for me please?

Comment: Do you mean "restriction"? By this, I mean the function $S$ which now has domain $\text{Im}(T)$. Thus, we're _restricting_ the domain. In other words, while $S$ might have taken any vector from $\mathbb{R}^n$ as input, the restriction of $S$ only takes vectors from $\text{Im}(T)$ as input. Note that $S$ and the restriction of $S$ don't necessarily have the same image or kernel.

Comment: Ok, I see this! However, I do not get how I use this result to derive the results. What do I do with ImT?